# TypeError: Cannot read property 'email' of undefined while using form with Multiple Inputs

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm a beginner in React and stuck with some problem.I'm getting an error as "TypeError: Cannot read property 'email' of undefined". Please find the error screenshot below:-

**SignIn.js**

```
    import React from 'react';
import {useState} from 'react';

export default function SignIn()
{
    const{forInp,setForm}=useState({
        email:"abc@gmail.com",
        password:""
    });
    
    function handleChange(event)
    {
        setForm({
            ...forInp,
            [event.target.name]:event.target.value});
    }

    function handleSubmit(event)
    {
        event.preventDefault();
        setForm({[event.target.name]:""});
       
    }   
    return(
        <div>
            <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
                <input type="email" name="email" value={forInp.email} placeholder="Email" onChange={handleChange}/>
                <input type="Password" name="password" value={forInp.password} placeholder="Password" onChange={handleChange}/>
                
                </form>
            </div>
    );
}
```

[image]

Comment: `useState` returns an array, not an object, so change `{forInp,setForm}` to be `[forInp, setForm]`

Answer (score 0):

Have modified the code where USeState's correct return format is being used,. rather than Object it returns array.
Following is the codesandbox link:

https://codesandbox.io/s/trusting-elbakyan-9h2sn?file=/src/SignIn.js

```
import React from "react";
import { useState } from "react";

export default function SignIn() {
  const [ forInp, setForm ] = useState({
    email: "abc@gmail.com",
    password: ""
  });

  function handleChange(event) {
    setForm({
      ...forInp,
      [event.target.name]: event.target.value
    });
  }

  function handleSubmit(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    setForm({ [event.target.name]: "" });
  }
  return (
    <div>
      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
        <input
          type="email"
          name="email"
          value={forInp.email}
          placeholder="Email"
          onChange={handleChange}
        />
        <input
          type="Password"
          name="password"
          value={forInp.password}
          placeholder="Password"
          onChange={handleChange}
        />
      </form>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    The correct way to useState is like 
    
    const[forInp,setForm]=useState({
            email:"abc@gmail.com",
            password:""
        });

we need to set two variable in array and assigned this array from useState

Here is reference link
https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to change this:

```
const{forInp,setForm}=useState({
        email:"abc@gmail.com",
        password:""
    });
```

to this:

```
const [ forInp, setForm ] = useState({
    email: "abc@gmail.com",
    password: ""
  });
```

**Explanation:**

React.useState returns an Array of `[ state, function ]`, not an Object.